Ansible vmware module keep getting permission denied
I'm writing a playbook to perform some VMware tasks. The first step is to gather VM facts. However, I'm keep getting permission denied error.
That's the part of my code for getting the VM facts:
- name: Find VM's facts
  community.vmware.vmware_guest_info:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    datacenter: "{{ vmware_datacentres[vcenter_hostname] }}"
    name: "{{ ansible_fqdn }}"
    validate_certs: false
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: vm_facts

- name: Debug vm_facts
  debug:
    var=vm_facts

Error message:
TASK [vmware-test : Find VM's facts] **************************************************************************************************
fatal: [testhost1 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "\n/bin/sh: /home/neil/venv/Ansible/bin/python3.11: Permission denied\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 126}

/home/neil/venv/Ansible/bin/python3.11 is the symbolic link to -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 7.6K Jun 20 02:05 /bin/python3.11
-vvv doesn't show any valuable information:
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1725915868.587364-136219-255490713105262 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1725915868.587364-136219-255490713105262="` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1725915868.587364-136219-255490713105262 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /home/neil/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/vmware/plugins/modules/vmware_guest_info.py
<localhost> PUT /home/neil/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-135815w4jkzmib/tmp311y27ef TO /tmp/ansible-tmp-1725915868.587364-136219-255490713105262/AnsiballZ_vmware_guest_info.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /tmp/ansible-tmp-1725915868.587364-136219-255490713105262/ /tmp/ansible-tmp-1725915868.587364-136219-255490713105262/AnsiballZ_vmware_guest_info.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=tobzmscvdwzdpmgluekcfjdklxdypfip] password:" -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-tobzmscvdwzdpmgluekcfjdklxdypfip ; /home/neil/venvs/Ansible/bin/python3.11 /tmp/ansible-tmp-1725915868.587364-136219-255490713105262/AnsiballZ_vmware_guest_info.py'"'"' && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1725915868.587364-136219-255490713105262/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'

The vcenter variables are stored in a separate var file. Credentials are correct.
Any thoughts?

If you log in as the same user Ansible is using, can you successfully run /home/neil/venv/Ansible/bin/python3.11?

Yes, I can source into the venv and execute python3.11

I must run it without root, so must set become: false in the playbook!
